# Don't see projectname.dll for process being debugged in Visual Studio Code

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm just learning VS Code and Angular, I've been following a tutorial online and trying to debug. After I start the debugger it asks me what process to attach too from a drop down list it provides.

According to the debugger, I should see a 'DatingApp.API.dll' process like the one in the tutorial here, as I've named my project the same as in the tutorial.

[image]

but what I see below doesn't have the .dll name, just -bash id

[image]

now I get this when I select .Net Core Attach in the debug section, instead of the .Net Core Launch (web) option

[image]

When I select .Net Core Launch (web) it automatically attaches to the app, but my question is why don't I see the process name 'DatingApp.API.dll' as an option and see '-bash 1730' instead?

'-bash 1730' is the process so I can connect using it, I'm just curious why it doesn't name it 'DatingApp.API.dll'?

Here is my launch.json file

```
{
 "version": "0.2.0",
 "configurations": [

    {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/DatingApp.API/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/DatingApp.API.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/DatingApp.API",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "launchBrowser": {
            "enabled": true
        },
        "env": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        },
        "sourceFileMap": {
            "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Attach",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little tricky, if you type in the search `DatingApp.API` it will show you `DatingApp.API.exe` as the only result, or at least that's what I got when tried. You can attached to it too.

[image]

And Voilá! Now you can debug your C# app.

[image]